# How to automatically add import in less from the react app

Tags: css, reactjs, less, create-react-app

I have an app created using `react-create-app` tool and I use a `style.less` file in `src/assets/less` that is compiled automatically.

In my `style.less` I import the style I have in the various react components in my app. I like the idea to have every component with his own style.less in there.

The first problem is the reference I have to add or update in the `src/assets/less/style.less`, every time I add a component or I rename it or I move it. Is there any way I can get all the import automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If your `webpack.config.js` is configured correctly, you should be able to import each components styles like:

`import './style.less';`